# Why my Uri , is not fetched by ACTION_DIAL in android?

Tags: java, android

I have found that the following code is working perfectly :

```
Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_DIAL , Uri.parse("tel:555-2368") );
```

But when I tried the code below, it is not working. I am trying to create a URI by reading from a file.

```
File f = new File ( "tushar.txt") ;
f.createNewFile() ;

fw = new FileWriter(f) ;
bfr = new BufferedWriter(fw);
bfr.write("9654309293") ;
bfr.write("9876543210") ;
Uri u = Uri.fromFile(f) ;

Intent intent =
new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, u);
```

Comment: Can you try with `bfr.flush();` before your "Uri u ="... line so that the data gets written to the file?

Answer (score 0):

try out this-

```
File f = new File ( "tushar.txt") ;
f.createNewFile() ;

fw = new FileWriter(f) ;
bfr = new BufferedWriter(fw);
bfr.write("tel:9654309293") ;
bfr.write("tel:9876543210") ;
bfr.flush();
fw.close();
Uri u = Uri.fromFile(f) ;

Intent intent =
new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, u);
```

Comment: what error it gives?plz paste it.why u r adding 2 number in file u can make call to one number at a time